# trying to upload photo to twitter using javascript and new update_with_media.json call

Tags: javascript, twitter, upload, photo

I am not using twitpic, trying to use new API but cannot find javascript examples and it is doing some strange stuff with the paramaters on the URLs because all of my other twitter API calls work fine

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1059

Comment: Erm .. I don't get this. What are you doing? What is wrong? Are you *now* or *not* using twitpic?

Comment: it clearly states "I am not using twitpic" so what is the confusion.

Comment: Have you found your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed some SSL or URL
As mentioned on Twitter page

**Important:** Make sure that you're using upload.twitter.com as your host while posting statuses with media. It is strongly recommended to use SSL with this method.

Source : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media

Comment: that is an interesting observation, but I am looking for sample code, that's all